# Apache2 rewrite failover domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to know if Apache2 rewrite module supports two URLs.

What I mean is when RewriteRule points to www1.example.com, if www1.example.com can't be reached, RewriteRule will point to www2.example.com.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to chain those. Put the 301 redirect inside the 404 response of ww1.test.com.

Comment: Hi AlienWebguy, thanks for your prompt reply,that is very helpful to me. But if www1.test.com host is down, this method doesn't work for me.So in this regard, I still want to know if it is possible that Rewrite module can handle this.

Comment: If you're asking if mod_rewrite can open an http connection to see if ww1.test.com is up or down and route the user based on the response headers, then no it can't. You'll need to use a server-side scripting language for that, or even better a load balancer.

Comment: Thank you. In originally I just want to see if I can use Apache rewrite and GEO modules (or nginx GEO) to load baclance the websites(or haproxy in different data centers), like F5 GTM so if one site is down, route the traffic to other available sites, comparing with Bind GEO.